# Lua attempt to call index global nil value error

Tags: lua, null, love2d

i'm new in lua programming. Trying to make a game based on platforms and physics. I couldn't get the probem. Please help. :( This is the part i get an error:

```lua
for i, obj in pairs(gameMap.layers["Platforms"].objects) do
   spawnPlatform(obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height)
end
```

and this is the error code:

```
Error

main.lua:25: attempt to call global 'spawnPlatform' (a nil value)


Traceback

main.lua:25: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: It's telling you in the error message; `spawnPlatform` is `nil`, i.e. it doesn't exist. That's really all I can tell you without knowing your code though.